# XHTML valid way to replace text with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
$("#FOO").hover(function() {
    $(this).html('<p><a href="somepage.php" target="_self">first text</a></p>');
    }, function() {
    $(this).html('<p><a href="somepage.php" target="_self">hovered text</a></p>');
});
```

Is it improper to put `<p>` & `<a>` tags in the .html function? It is invalid XHTML and I'd like to make it cleaner.
thanks!

from w3c validator:
Error Line 134, Column 83: end tag for element "A" which is not open

the next error is "end tag for element "p" wich is not open. its just reading those tags weird.

`….html('<p><a href="somepage.php" target="_self">first text</a></p>')`;

Comment: target is not a valid XHTML attribute.

Comment: What kind of element is #FOO?

Comment: #FOO is a generic name for the div

Comment: Sounds like some other part of your HTML is broken.  Does it validate when you comment that code out?

Comment: @John - yes it validates w/o the jquery code - there's no tags before this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine. You could use a `$("#FOO p")` selector if its really bothering you.

Comment: Not necessarily.  What if #FOO is an <h1> tag?

Comment: Could also use: $('#FOO > p > a').text()

P.S.: Kyle: #FOO p is slower than #FOO > p

Comment: haha, the jQuery selector speed enhancements will never end =)